# clould foundry dataflow server basic auth

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

We are using SCDF on PCF with File-based Authentication, it works fine on a single instance - however when we scale to 2 or more instances, it fails on login stating "Not Logged in" - there's no error message on the server..

Does SCDF store user info in session ? Not sure why login not working when scaled up

SCDF - 1.5.1.RELEASE

(Apparently it was working in 1.3.0.RELEASE)

Answer (score 0):

The file-based authentication is not a recommended approach for cloud platforms like PCF.

In PCF in particular, you'd want to take advantage of the single-sign-on solution provided by the platform. With OAuth and SSO backed by UAA, it'd be a consistent security experience regardless of the number of instances. Please refer to the write-up on [authentication options available for SCDF on PCF](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/1.7.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-security-cloud-foundry).

With this, you can centrally also renew an expired OAuth token or even revoke them as needed.

Also, as an FYI, when using the [SCDF Tile](https://docs.pivotal.io/scdf/1-2/#features), all this is automatically configured for you. You'd create an instance of SCDF service from the marketplace and the space-developer can gain access to the Dashboard, REST-APIs, and Shell - all of it works on an SSO model by default.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't use the SSO/UAA because jobs are triggered from autosys cURL (at this point we don't have a mechanism to retrive or send the token in the request) and we needed simple mechanism to secure SCDF and choose basic auth. If you are saying basic auth doesn't work with SCDF and PCF (when autoscale is enabled), then we need think of some other mechanism to secure SCDF

Comment: Just wanted to add that we don't have a SCDF Tile in our PCF at this point, we have deployed it as an App

Comment: Currently, we use a simple in-memory [`MapSessionRepository`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-common-security-config/blob/00969a45495639fa344cead5ebcb3ae5ed696772/spring-cloud-common-security-config-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/common/security/BasicAuthSecurityConfiguration.java#L76) to keep track of the logged-in user. That's why when you scale the application, they aren't consistently available for all instances. We talked about "Sticky Sessions" as an option in CF, but all of the CF users preferred the OAuth. Feel free to open an issue & consider contributing.

Comment: Just to be clear, the explanation above is specific to Basic-Auth in SCDF. Generally, it is not a preferred approach for production workloads.